the ui layout about column and shift in its element in semantic-ui
I am a newbie to semantic-ui, and I meet a problem about ui layout, the code snippets is like this:
<div class="ui message" style="width:850px !important;">
  <div class="ui form" style="width:850px !important;">
    <div class="ui column doubling stackable grid">
      <div class="four wide column">
        <select id="select1" class="ui dropdown"> 
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="four wide column">
        <select id="select1" class="ui dropdown"> 
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="six wide column"></div>
      <div class="two wide column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui column doubling stackable grid">
      <div class="two wide column" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <div class="ui two wide  icon buttons"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fourteen wide column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

The layout of select, will be shift down to its parent columns about 10px; and when using
debug mode in chrome, I found all select are not logically lie inside the columns boundary, they are  shift to right and down, and excess the column boundary. So, all the doms in ui message will be excess to its boundary in final ui displaying. Is there any good way to cover that, and is any one know the exact reason why its go like this way. My version is 2.0.3, and developed in asp webform, thanks a lot.
